# How can I find the longest sequence of matching letters in a string?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm new in JavaScript and I'm trying to find the max value of same letters in row. I have a number of letters in string but I don't know what to do next.

Will be grateful for help.

There is my code:

```js
let myString = "aaaAAAwwwwkkaaaaalllkk"


function countLetters(myString){
    let lowcase = myString.toLowerCase();
    let tempArr = lowcase.split('');
    let letters = [];
    let count = 1;

    for(i = 0 ; i < tempArr.length; i++){
        if(tempArr[i] === tempArr[i+1]){
            count++;
        }
        else{
            let value = `${count},${tempArr[i]}`;
            letters = [...letters, value];
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    return letters
}
console.log(countLetters(myString))
```

Comment: What you need as output of your method? Number of repeated letters, letter that is repeated most or maybe both?

Comment: You are off to a great start :) A bit more info on your desired outcome would be a great help :)

Comment: Well i need a letter that is repeated most, also when i change string for another letters.

Comment: [`'xxaaaAAAwwwwkkaaaaalllkk'.match(/(.)\1*/gis).reduce((val, str) => (val.length >= str.length) ? val : str);`](https://regex101.com/r/SXx3Jy/1/) gives you the precise substring value of the first matching, longest possible sequence of equal characters, ignoring their upper/lowercase variants. Thus the above expression returns `'aaaAAA'`. It's `length` property gives you the character count.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to identify the chunks that have a repeating character:

```js
function countLetters(myString) {
    return myString.toLowerCase()
                   .match(/(.)\1*/gs)
                   .reduce((acc, s) => s.length > acc.length ? s : acc, "");
}

let myString = "xxaaaAAAwwwwkkaaaaalllkk"
console.log(countLetters(myString))
```

This returns the (lowercased) longest substring that consists of the same (case-insensitive) character.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to keep some state as you loop through the string (which is just an array of characters). We'll need to know what letter we're currently counting, and how many we've seen, plus the largest value we have seen.

As you loop through the array, if you find the same letter you've been processing, you increment the count. Otherwise, you first have to save the current count into the final result, then resetting the rest of the local state.

All together, it ends up like this:

```
function countLetters(myString) {
    let previous = '', // nothing matches this
        count = 0,
        result = { letter: '', count: 0 };

    for (const letter of myString.toLowerCase()) {
        if (letter === previous) {
            count++;
        }
        else {
            if (result !== null && count > result.count) {
                result = { letter: previous, count: count };
            }

            previous = letter;
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Edited to return the letter that had the longest streak.

Comment: Do u know how to return also letter for this result ? Cuz I tying to do by ourself, but i dont have idea for this :/

Comment: Updated, returns an object now with letter and count, with sensible defaults

Comment: Nice, now i will study code to understand how it works, Thanks alot :)

Comment: @pavlindrom ... your current implementation returns the wrong result ... for `countLetters("aaaAAAwwwwkkaaaaalllkk")` one gets `{letter: "a", count: 5}` which is not correct because it presents the last sequence of `aaaaa`. But it should match with `aaaAAA` thats length/count of cause is `6`.

Comment: @JakubCzekalski ... do you need any more detailed information about *trincot*'s or mine approach? Is the regex based solution already too much to comprehend?

Comment: @PeterSeliger assuming case sensitive unless the requirements state it needs to be case insensitive.

Comment: @pavlindrom ... OP made it perfectly clear. Within OP's code it states `let lowcase = myString.toLowerCase(); let tempArr = lowcase.split('');` and the rest continues operating upon `tempArr` which contains lower case characters only.

Comment: @PeterSeliger okay, fixed - thanks, I didn't catch that!